# TWIG: What is the similar instruction to PHP's $$var?

Tags: twig

I get an array in view and I only know the name (string) of a variable.

I need to evaluate it.

How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twig doesn't have variable variables but you can make a twig extension / filter that would sort that problem and it shouldn't be very difficult.

Here is how to do one, in case you haven't been working with this:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html